# how to update mootools version in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, mootools

I don't know why joomla is not updating mootools with their updated version, joomla 1.5 still use mootools v 1.1, i tried to replace it with  latest mootools  version, but results are horrible, website stops working, everthing gone worst.

so please suggest me how to update mootools version into joomla without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 1.5.20 has plug-in for the Mootools 1.2.4 called ["Mootools 1.2.4 Upgrade"](http://docs.joomla.org/What_is_the_Mootools_1.2.4_upgrade_plugin%3F), but the plug-in is disabled by default.

If you are making a clean installation go "Admin->Tools->Plug-ins" find and enabled "Mootools 1.2.4 upgrade plugin".

If you are updating older Joomla system to 1.5.20, the plugin will be installed but it will not be visible because it will not have plug-in record in the database, therefore the plugin cannot be used. Here is a tutorial showing how to add this plugin when updating Joomla system from older version - http://www.boolcast.com/updates/mootools-124-upgrade-plugin-for-joomla-15.

Answer (score 1):

Now that [Mootools core 1.2.5](http://mootools.net/download) is out, i'd bet on it (hopefully) for J!1.6 RC.
And be aware that 1.5.20 mootools.js (in mtupdate plugin) contains More 1.2.4.2 (current version version is More 1.2.4.4).

Answer (score 0):

Search the Joomla forums, there are several threads on updating Mootools.

In general, you can update the frontend pretty easily (assuming you don't want the built in Joomla functions or have components that rely on them). The backend is more problematic as it's built heavily around 1.1

Having said all of that, the latest versionof Joomla 1.5.20 has a plugin to allow you to update to 1.2. You could try updating?

Comment: Or wait for Joomla 1.6. Anyone knows what version of MooTools it will use?

Comment: Looks like 1.6 will have Moo 1.2.4, but that's the same that you get with the upgrade in 1.5.20 I think.